# Fill map with color D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new in Javascript and D3.JS
I have this code to create a map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body{
    background-color:#0B3861;
}    
path {
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
  fill: #dfdfdf;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 1000,
    height = 600;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([-5,45])
    .scale(200)
    .rotate([0,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");


     d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/d3noob/5193723/raw/6e1434b2c2de24aedde9bcfe35f6a267bd2c04f5/world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {


    g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
      .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I would like to color some country in red and other in blue.
I have an other CSV file like this:
country, sentiment

France, 1

USA, 0

So if the sentiment is 1 I would like to fill the country in red.

Could someone help me ?
thanks in advance

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `style` at your path

`.style("fill", 'red');`

Randomly blue, red colors to countries :

```
const colors = ['white', 'blue', 'red'];

g.selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
  .geometries)
   .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", () => colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1]);
```

[Codepen of your code with filled countries](http://codepen.io/AvraamMavridis/pen/aZbQze)

Comment: Thanks you for this answer. What if I want, instead of the math random, use another file ( csv for example ) with two columns id and color: 84, 2. in this case I would like the country 84 with the color red.

Comment: load your csv and then map your data with it and use inside the `fill` to something like `.style("fill", ( d ) => d.id === ? 'red' : 'blue')`

Comment: Prepare your data as distinct list: [ id1, color1 ], [id2, color2]... then use scale: global_colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.id;}));).range(data.map(function(d) { return d.color;}));)
then .style("fill", function(d) { return global_colorScale(d.id); })

Comment: for me the code that showed 3 colors was `colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]`